# How to set the ScrollPanel scrolling position when the panel is hidden

Tags: gwt

I have a ScrollPanel and I want to reset his scrolling position when it is hidden.
To do so I call the scrollTop method. As I can see it is not working when the ScrollPanel is hidden.

Here a sample code:

```
public void onModuleLoad() {
    StringBuilder html = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i<1000; i++) html.append("row "+i+"<br>");

    HTMLPanel content = new HTMLPanel(html.toString());

    final ScrollPanel scrollPanel = new ScrollPanel(content);
    scrollPanel.setHeight("200px");
    RootPanel.get().add(scrollPanel);


    RootPanel.get().add(new Button("TEST", new ClickHandler() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
            scrollPanel.scrollToTop();
            scrollPanel.setVisible(false);
            scrollPanel.scrollToBottom();
            scrollPanel.setVisible(true);
        }
    }));
}
```

After clicking the TEST button the ScrollPanel keep is top position.
Any idea how to scroll it when hidden?

Answer (score 0):

You can't scroll a hidden element because it does not have an offset position, i.e. both "top" and "bottom" would return zero.

See a possible solution: http://blog.gaijindesign.com/jquery-scrolltop-to-a-hidden-element/

Comment: Top and bottom values are not the only issues. I've tried setting the vertical scroll position manually, but the scroll position is reset to the old value (the one in visible state) when I make the panel again visible.

Comment: Setting a scroll position manually will not work for the same reason - a hidden element does not have a "position".

Comment: This is a known and expected behavior. http://blog.gaijindesign.com/jquery-scrolltop-to-a-hidden-element/